# What off-hand item do I use with a bow-equipped Demon Hunter?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-demon-hunter

When a Demon Hunter is using a crossbow, he can use a shield or even another crossbow in his off-hand at the same time. But when he equips a bow, the shield is removed, and the spot for off-hand item show a quiver for arrows.

What item can I use in my off-hand?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**You can use quivers, which are Demon Hunter-specific items.**

Unlike in *Diablo 2*, you don't need bow ammo. Now the quivers are a way to provide additional character bonuses—most quivers come with a damage boost and other magic item properties.

Comment: I've found some quivers give hate regeneration, which is nice.

Comment: There are a whole host of magical properties that quivers can give.  Listing them all would take too long here.