# What parameters are taken in account in "stat changes if equipped" tooltips?

Tags: diablo-iii

I have two items shown below. Tooltip on new bow shows that I'd have 43.3 damage decrease, however actually equipping it boosts damage on character sheet from 1639.70 to 2094.44.

After thinking a little, I figured out this is due to DH's "Archery" +15% bow bonus not being taken in account on tooltips.

What parameters exactly are taken in account in those "stat changes if equipped" tooltips and what are ignored?

[image: Old bowvs. new]

(I've had additional question what is better in the end, but it is already covered in: [Is there a non-DPS reason to favour a crossbow/hand crossbow/bow?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66841/is-there-a-non-dps-reason-to-favour-a-crossbow-hand-crossbow-bow), as mentioned by Alok).

Answer (score 1):

Its unclear if your actual question is about the disparity between tooltip and character screen damage values; or the difference between bow & crossbow. Re. tooltip, there are a lot of other factors involved such as skills, runes, quiver etc. that can affect the actual values.

To answer the question, *do equipping higher damage bow vs. crossbow have drawbacks*:
perhaps the question [Is there a non-DPS reason to favour a crossbow/hand crossbow/bow?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66841/is-there-a-non-dps-reason-to-favour-a-crossbow-hand-crossbow-bow) is what you're looking for?

Also, note that higher critical damage on crossbows helps more if you use Sharpshooter and tend to do few attacks spread out over time, or if you have a lot of +Crit Chance items.

Comment: Both, really, but since reason to use one or another are indeed covered by that another question, I think I'll reformulate question to: "what is taken in account and what is not in 'stat changes' tooltip?"